# Adding a system user to an LDAP group with SSSD

Tags: authentication, group, ldap, sssd

Our LDAP server is running RFC 2307 groups (`memberuid` contains a username, not a DN). With our old `nscd`/`nss_ldap`/`pam_ldap` setup, you could list a non-LDAP user (a system user from `/etc/passwd`) in an LDAP group's `memberuid` attribute, and that system user will be a member of the group.

However, on machines I've upgraded to [SSSD](https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/), this no longer works: SSSD just strips out the non-LDAP user from the member list.

I've confirmed this behavior by logging in as the user and using `id` and also by running `getent group group`.

Here is my `sssd.conf` (with some details redacted and clearly marked as such)

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
domains = REDACTED.net

[nss]
# defaults are OK

[pam]
# defaults are OK

[domain/REDACTED.net]
enumerate = true
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
access_provider = ldap
chpass_provider = ldap

ldap_uri = _srv_
ldap_chpass_uri = ldap://haruhi.REDACTED.net
ldap_search_base = dc=REDACTED,dc=net?subtree?
ldap_schema = rfc2307
ldap_tls_cacert = /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/REDACTED-CA.crt
ldap_id_use_start_tls = true
ldap_pwd_policy = shadow

ldap_access_filter = memberOf=cn=UNIX Users,ou=Policies,dc=REDACTED,dc=net
ldap_access_order = filter, authorized_service, host

ldap_default_bind_dn = uid=haruhi,ou=Machines,dc=REDACTED,dc=net
ldap_default_authtok = VERY_REDACTED
```

`/etc/nsswitch.conf` has boring entries for passwd/group/shadow:

```
passwd:         compat ldap sss
group:          compat ldap sss
shadow:         compat sss
```

(ldap is still in there, but it isn't actually installed on the system any more)

Also, I doubt it matters (as I see the same behavior on other machines) but this machine—Haruhi—is also the master LDAP server, running OpenLDAP.

**How do I configure SSSD to *not* strip out system users from LDAP groups?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was enabled in sssd 1.9.5, by setting sssd.conf to include:

```
ldap_rfc2307_fallback_to_local_users = true
```

https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/wiki/Releases/Notes-1.9.5

Comment: Backport from Jessie to Wheezy is reasonably easy to build (only had to chase down a few dependencies) and it works.